# Android HttpUrlConnection result string truncated

Tags: java, android, xml, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am currently developing an Android application and encounter the following problem.
I am making an HTTP request to a server that is supposed to send me back XML content that I then parse. I noticed recurring errors while parsing long XML strings so I decided to display the result of my requests and discovered that the string (or the stream?) that I receive is randomly truncated. Sometimes I get the whole string, sometimes half, sometimes a third, and it seems to follow a certain pattern in the amount of characters that are truncated, what I mean by that is that I sometimes get 320 characters after a request then 156 after the next then 320 twice, then 156 again (these aren't the actual numbers but it follows a pattern).

Here is my code for the request and conversion of the InputStream into a string:

```
private String downloadUrlGet(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 20000 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 20000;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

    // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
    // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        } 
    }
}

// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
private String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

The length of the XML that I try to retrieve is much less than 20000.
I tried to use HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode() with 0 and various other numbers as parameter but it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: in your "readIt" your read input stream just one time, getting small chunk of data from buffer. You need to repeat reading it until it ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the usual mistake of assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. See the Javadoc. It isn't obliged to do that. It isn't obliged to transfer more than one byte as a matter of fact. You need to read in a loop until you have encountered end of stream (`read()` returns -1).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work by reading the stream one character at a time and appending it to a String but I still can't figure out how to make it work using a buffer and read(char[] buffer, int offset, int count) like they do it in the official Android tutorial...

Comment: `while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { str += new String(buffer, 0, count); }`

Comment: The above method of reading a string is wrong if you're using multi-byte encoding (e.g. UTF-8). If the buffer ends half way a multi-byte character, this will throw. Instead use a `StreamReader` or something like that.